# Logging errors when argument and value fail conditions

Tags: bash

I want to detect numeric arguments passed to the option `-p`.  If the value is not numeric, I want to log appropriate errors.

Am I missing anything with the following bash code?

```
pary=("-p+([[:digit:]])" "-p")
local predicate=""
for gpn in "${pary[@]}"  # Loop through possible short options
do

  case $arg1 in
   ($gpn)
       if [[ "$gpn" == *"+([[:digit:]])" ]]; then
         predicate="VERIFIED"
         _vl="${arg1:2}"
         _sf=1
         break
       elif [[ $arg2 == +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
         predicate="VERIFIED"
         _vl="${arg2}"
         _sf=2
         break
       else
         _vl=0
         _sf=1
         _error+=("$arg2 failed numeric validation")
         break
       fi
       ;;
  esac

done
```

Comment: For user programs, error text is traditionally written to stderr as in `>&2 echo "your error text"`.

Comment: I am first accumulating all errors together rather that stopping at the first error encountered.

Comment: Is the else part necessary after testing the `gpn` pattern ?

Comment: If you're not writing a compiler, accumulating errors is a pretty bad idea. Fail fast is a thing. Just ask yourself how much earlier you would have been done if you hadn't tried to write complicated error handling code that itself has to be debugged.

Comment: Quite right.  My original idea for to inform the user amount all the errors in a single instant. Have encountered the school of though that continues processing as much as possible.  But as you say, that was actually about program language design.

Comment: Or a design born out of a golden age when people used punch cards, JCL, and 5 hour turnaround time.